# Search DB with multiple criteria but when date is not selected no results are shown

Tags: php

I have a db search to display results based on selected criteria, one of the criteria is a date range, plus 3 other criteria.The searching works well, I can search by date range only to display all results or I can search a date range and add 1, 2 or all 3 of the other variables..however If I leave date range out no results are displayed.  Using mysql db.

```
Search page::

$term1 = $_REQUEST['term1'];
$term2 = $_REQUEST['term2'];
$term3 = $_REQUEST['term3'];
$term4 = $_REQUEST['term4'];
$term5 = $_REQUEST['term5'];

$terms= '&term1='.$term1 . '&term2='.$term2 . '&term3='.$term3 . '&term4='.$term4 . '&term5='.$term5;

$limit=15;

$sql ="SELECT * FROM ircb WHERE cdate BETWEEN '$term2' AND '$term3' AND staff  LIKE '%$term1%'  AND item LIKE '%$term4%' AND service LIKE '%$term5%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $start_from, 15";


$rs_result = mysql_query ($sql);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs_result);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ircb WHERE cdate BETWEEN '$term2' AND '$term3' AND staff  LIKE '%$term1%'  AND item LIKE '%$term4%' AND service LIKE '%$term5%'"); 
$number=mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Term 2 and term 3 are the date range terms entered from a date picker and put in proper format of 000-00-00, I assume the issue is the WHERE statement
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that will be the issue. Ideally you would set default values of the date string to cover all possible dates in the event the dates aren't set or are 0000-00-00.

For example:

```
if((!isset($_REQUEST['term2'])) OR ($_REQUEST['term2'] == '0000-00-00')) {
    $term2 = '1970-01-01';
}
if((!isset($_REQUEST['term3'])) OR ($_REQUEST['term3'] == '0000-00-00')) {
    $term3 = date("Y-m-d");
}
```

So in the event the date terms aren't set, it will use default values spanning the specified date range (up to the current date).